# iOS 6 Core Bluetooth - Unknow error 128

Tags: ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

While using iOS 6.0 and our custom device using the BT LE GATT profile - we are seeing this unusual error

**CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Unknown error: 128**

BTW this is an iOS 6.0 only problem as we don't have this problem on iOS 5.1 and everything works smoothly there.

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Quite strange, since `CBError` goes from 0 to 17...

Comment: @Larme where is CBError defined? I got CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Unknown error: 2, when I call readValueForCharacteristic on a characteristic after it's set to notifying state.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Constants/Reference/reference.html